# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier - opening Twitter share in new window

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, anchor, new-window

I'm trying to create share links for my site that open in new windows for Facebook, Google Plus and Twitter. The Facebook and g+ links work fine, but the Twitter one is throwing me an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` error and not opening anything. Could it have something to do with the prefilled status? The URL on its own is working fine. It is only the addition of the opening in a new window that's been causing errors.

Twitter:

```
   <a href='#' onclick="window.open('https://twitter.com/home?status=Message','width=1100,height=500');">
   <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/header_07.png"/>
   </a>
```

Google Plus:

```
  <a href='#' onclick="window.open('https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://staging.example.org','mywindow','width=1100,height=500');">
  <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/header_05.png"/>
  </a>
```

Comment: The code works nice for me check [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e37d5ged/)

Comment: Per @Ethaan's comment, this does not appear to be reproducible. Could you provide more detail as to what *identifier* is appearing unexpectedly in your error message and the related code in which it occurs within?

Comment: @Ethaan, @Anthony Forloney, my issue is that I am not sure what the identifier in reference is. My console just references the line the entire twitter `<a>` tag is on.

Comment: Also, as I saw in @Ethaan's fiddle, the page is opening in a new tab rather than new window as I indented.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still baffled by the issue I was running into before, but I tried a different approach for my Twitter share and got the following code to work:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/home?status=MESSAGE"
onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=260,width=600');return false;">
```